# Firebase and Google Popup Authentication not fully authenticating

Tags: firebase, google-api, firebase-authentication

I have two Firebase projects that use the same front end web app and in my code when I paste in the Firebase web code snippet from Project1 into the code and I login with Google, Project 1 shows I am signed in and my my google profile pic and user name show:

[image: 1]

when I paste into my same web app the Firebase code snippet from Project2, and I login with Google, Project 2 does not get my profile pic url and name, both are valued as null:

[image: 2]

I've poured over my settings in Firebase Authentication and in the Google API Service Console, but I can't find where the hold up is. Any help to point me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase-auth stores the auth session in web storage (localStorage/indexedDB) which is single host origin. I assume both projects are using different domains. If so, then the auth state (web storage) of one site will not be accessible from the other.